# How to correctly restore Gtk window size at program startup?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I am writing application in C# using GTK# GUI framework to make it cross-platform.
Many things are being done in GTK# not like in WPF/Windows.Forms, but most of them I was able to solve on my own.

There is a "little" problem, what became not that "little" when I tried to solve it.
I am saving window position and maximized flag to config file when application is being closed.
But when I am trying to restore window parameters, they are being restored not correctly.

Methods I tried to use:

SetSizeRequest():

```
this.SetSizeRequest((int)config["windowwidth"], (int)config["windowheight"]);
```

SetDefaultSize():

```
this.SetDefaultSize((int)config["windowwidth"], (int)config["windowheight"]);
```

Resize():

```
this.Resize((int)config["windowwidth"], (int)config["windowheight"]);
```

The problem is:
Some of these methods does not work at all (change nothing). Others behave strangely: set window size to not the one was loaded from config, make window continuously expanding, etc.

I am also adding a constraint on size of one specific widget:

```
Gdk.Geometry geom = new Gdk.Geometry();
geom.MinWidth = 800;
geom.MinHeight = 400;
this.SetGeometryHints(BoxNotebook, geom, Gdk.WindowHints.MinSize);
```

When I use all this together, it is becoming a complete mess. 
What is the correct way to restore window size at program startup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Resize` works in my application. Are you sure that the correct values are being loaded from the config file?

**EDIT**

Here is a Glade file that seems to do what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<interface>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <child>
      <object class="GtkHPaned" id="hpaned">
        <child>
          <object class="GtkNotebook" id="notebook">
            <property name="width_request">300</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow">
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview"/>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child type="tab">
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
                <property name="label">300 px wide</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="tab_fill">False</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="resize">True</property>
            <property name="shrink">False</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label2">
            <property name="width_request">400</property>
            <property name="label">400 px wide</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="resize">False</property>
            <property name="shrink">False</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: Well I'm doing that in Window constructor, after Build() call. May be that is wrong. May be I should do it in some Window signal handler? Activated or some other?

Comment: okay it worked for me when I called it from Main() after calling win.Show();
Although, sometimes, when the requisition of children widgets is high, the window starts to stretch horizontally forever.
Is there a way to limit max window width?
I dont like window width to exceed screen width.

Comment: I use `Resize` in my window constructor as well, and it works. Perhaps you're trying to cram too much into a window? When do the childrens' requisitions get too large? Can you solve it by putting some things in `ScrolledWindow`s?

Comment: Actually there is such structure:
HPaned in the window; Notebook on the left pane; ScrolledWindow in the Notebook; ListView in the ScrolledWindow.
I want this notebook never have less width than 300 pixels, whole right pane of HPaned - less than 400 pixels.
I want the window to be resizable, and right pane of HPaned to stay same size when window is being resized.
It seems it is impossible to achieve.
I've made right pane to keep its size. I've made window resizable.
But when I add described limits, window becomes not resizable.

Comment: And when I don't add the limits, if window is resized so Notebook becomes too small (less than width of one icon in ListView), window starts to expand eternally.

Comment: I'm hitting the wall with my head atm, since I don't see the way to make it work correctly and behave user-friendly :(

Comment: I have a Glade file that seems to do what you describe in your comment. I'll edit it into my answer.

Comment: Well, it works fine, but it still allows left pane to have 0 pixels width, it kinda screws its contents. It is not critical tho, it is ok like this.
One last little problem: on windows platform, when I resize window (increasing width), left part of right pane content is being redrawn weirdly, adding some kind of "artifacts" on its look. May be that is a bug in current Gtk# version. Thank you anyway for your help :)